# Python: Why it always asks to install pyparsing whenever I want install something?

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-14.04, pyparsing

I'm not sure why pip always throw the exception that 'can not find pyparsing'. 
even When I try to download pyparsing i get:

```
pip install pyparsing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
ImportError: No module named pyparsing
```

It doesn't make sense?!

Comment: Try uninstalling it and installing it again.

Comment: A pyparsing-based parser has been added to the `packaging` module, so you now have an install-time dependency. As @BilltheLizard suggests, see if uninstalling your current pyparsing helps. The most recent version of pyparsing (v 2.2.0) includes some specialized setup code to try to break this cyclic dependency.

Comment: even When I do sudo pip uninstall pyparsing, I get the same error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    import packaging.requirements
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
ImportError: No module named pyparsing

Comment: Ok, this is a total desperation move - pyparsing is very small, just a single Python file, pyparsing.py. You can get it from sourceforge at https://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/pyparsing.py - I think you should be able to wget it, and then copy it to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/packaging/. Hopefully this will give you a semi-working pip, at which point, use it to update your `packaging` and `pyparsing` modules to the latest versions.

Answer (score 3):

Even after I did what Shahin and Paul said, I still get the same error. So I removed pip and reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Sounds like a much better solution than my suggestion. Did this fix your problem?

Comment: yes, it fixed it. It looks like it was in a loop so the only solution that worked was to totally reinstall pip.

Comment: Thanks, this solution has worked multiple times on multiple machines like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try Downloading the wheel file and install

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/6a/8a/718fd7d3458f9fab8e67186b00abdd345b639976bc7fb3ae722e1b026a50/pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=7247e7896688eff4bc8c7fc5d0cdd2b0
pip install pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

In case you face any issue with wget command download , you can get the wheel file from the following link

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/2.2.0#downloads